# How to post map rout on facebook

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, dictionary, facebook-opengraph

I have one fitness application. when user start to run then route start to get draw and when user stop then route get completed now as I have map route so i want to post this map route on the facebook for that I have checked documentation of facebook and I have found something like

```
NSMutableDictionary<FBGraphObject> *action = [FBGraphObject graphObject];action[@"course"] = @"http://samples.ogp.me/136756249803614";

[FBRequestConnection startForPostWithGraphPath:@"me/fitness.walks"
                                   graphObject:action
                             completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                                 id result,
                                                 NSError *error) {
                                 // handle the result
                             }];
```

they are giving reference for "course"

link for course is this https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/object-type/fitness.course
but i dont have any clue how to use this

and Facebook documentation is this 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/action-type/fitness.walks

It would be great help If someone show me way how to use this all and post map route on facebook 
will be great help thank you

Comment: Look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16354597/1228075

Comment: thats my answer buddy he he :] i asked this question here but then after i found solution  by my self and then some body asked same kind of question and i answered :]

Comment: Oh haha sorry I didn't realize!