# how to post route map on facebook not image

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api

facebook is providing new feature to post route map and not image of map. i have checked their documentation and I found this code but i am getting much what to do

they have given this kind of code

```
NSMutableDictionary<FBGraphObject> *action = [FBGraphObject graphObject];action[@"course"] = @"http://samples.ogp.me/136756249803614";

[FBRequestConnection startForPostWithGraphPath:@"me/fitness.walks"
                                   graphObject:action
                             completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                                 id result,
                                                 NSError *error) {
                                 // handle the result
                             }];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done this. you can not do this with only IOS you need to use Php you need to send array of longitude and latitude to php side and then from php side posting on that map on facebook my job was on IOS i do not know how to do at PHP side

Comment: thank you i will ask php developer about this